# GNU Make does not ignore failed command

Tags: gnu-make

I have written a rule where a directory should be removed if it exists:

```
.PHONY: distclean
distclean:
    -rmdir release
```

`make distclean` prints:

```
rmdir release
rmdir: failed to remove ‘release’: No such file or directory
test.mak:3: recipe for target 'distclean' failed
make: [distclean] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Shouldn't the `-` sign make GNU Make ignore the error?

I am using GNU Make 4.0.

Comment: It should, and it does, that's what "Error 1 (ignored)" means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make is ignoring the error:

```
make: [distclean] Error 1 (ignored)
```

It still prints the error messages, but if you add another rule in the `distclean` target it should be processed in spite of the `rmdir` failure.

In more detail:

```
rmdir release
```

This is `make` printing the command it's about to run.

```
rmdir: failed to remove ‘release’: No such file or directory
```

This is `rmdir` printing an error message because `release` doesn't exist. To remove that, you'd add `2> /dev/null` to the command (or `>& /dev/null` to silence `rmdir` completely).

```
test.mak:3: recipe for target 'distclean' failed
```

`rmdir` exits with a non-zero exit code, so `make` prints an error message. To remove that, you'd add `|| true` to the command (so that it exits with a zero exit code in all cases).

```
make: [distclean] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Finally, since the command was prefixed with `-`, the error is ignored and `make` continues.

Comment: Thanks.  I was confused by the `recipe for target 'distclean' failed` message.  I was expecting a silent behaviour.  As you say, successive recipes are executed.